# Appended elements are not showing CSS ISSUE JAVASCRIPT PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have experiencing some problems with fetching the **grandchilds** from my db table: **referrals**. However, it seems that my code can actually fetch the **usernamee** of my **grandchilds**. But it is not appearing below my **child's** line and **there is no error in INSPECT**.

Please see the **OUTPUT** image I attached here: 
Attached here are the images of the output of my code:

[image: OUTPUT]

This is the UPDATED database table name referrals: 
[image]

I used Javascript to fetch the data's inside **"referrals"** table

```
<!-- GENEOLOGY TREE -->
    <div class="tree">
       <?php $id = 1; ?>
          <ul>
             <li>
               <div id="parent_account"><a href="#"><img src="user.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:50px"/></br>Parent<?php echo $id; ?></a></div>
             </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
<!-- END OF GENOLOFY TREE -->


  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // start get children
    var _id = "<?php echo $id ?>";
    var child = "";
    var child_id = [];
    var gchild_id = [];
    var count = 0;

    $.post('get_child_referrals.php', { id:_id }).done(function(response){
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        var referred = response["referred"];
        var referred_len = response["referred"].length;
        if(referred_len > 0){
            child += "<ul>";
            for(var x = 0; x < referred_len; x++) {
                console.log(referred[x]["usernamee"]);
                count += 1;
                child_id[x] = referred[x]["id"];
                child += "<li id='child"+x+"'><a href="+x+"><img src='user.png' alt='Avatar' style='width:50px'/><br>Child "+referred[x]["usernamee"]+"</a></li>";
            }
            child += "</ul>";
            console.log(child);
            $("#parent_account").append(child);
            // start get grandchildren
        // console.log(child_id);
        var gchild_len = child_id.length;
        // console.log(gchild_len);
        for(i = 0; i < gchild_len; i++){
            gchild = "";
            _id = child_id[i];
            // console.log(_id);
            $.post('get_child_referrals.php', { id:_id }).done(function(response){
                gresponse = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                greferred = gresponse["referred"];
                greferred_len = gresponse["referred"].length;
                if(greferred_len > 0){
                    gchild += "<ul>";
                    for(y = 0; y < greferred_len; y++) {
                        gchild_id[y] = greferred[y]["id"];
                        console.log(greferred[y]["usernamee"]);
                        gchild += "<li id='gchild"+y+"'><a href="+y+"><img src='user.png' alt='Avatar' style='width:50px'/><br>Child "+greferred[y]["usernamee"]+"</a></li>";
                    }
                    gchild += "</ul>";
                    console.log($("#child"+i).length);
                    console.log(gchild);
                    $("#child"+i).append(gchild);
                }
            });
        }
        // end get grandchildren
        }
    });
    // end get children
});
</script>​
```

**get_child_referrals.php**

```
include('connectdb.php');
$response = array();
$response["referred"] = array();
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM referrals WHERE referral_id='$id'"; // MY RECRUITERS
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                array_push($response["referred"], $data);
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

**For more info, this is my logs on my inspect console:**
[image]

Comment: What have you tried to narrow the problem down? Is the AJAX request running successful? Does it contain the expected data?

Comment: Yes, the ajax is running successfully. I can also see the username's of my grandchild which is 'grandchild 1 of child 1' and 'grandchild 2 of child 1' in INSPECT. So yes it contains the expected data @NicoHaase

Comment: I have updated my post, and inserted a picture containing my logs in my console. Thank you. @NicoHaase

Comment: can you do a console log of `child` and `gchild` vars on the line just before you append it to make sure you've got the correct elements?

Comment: Hi. I have updated my post, i added console log for child and gchild before the append line. I got the correct elements for grandchilds @PaddyHallihan

Comment: Just try changing the code as below.And check if its the output you want.
     $("#child"+il).append(gchild); 
to 
 $("#child"+(il-1 )).append(gchild);
And please check if you have some logical error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,Inspect for the username.Check if its coming in HTML.Sometimes, it is rendered but hidden.Secondly, just just console the child element,to confirm you are appending it to the right one.

console.log($(child));

I tried your code in my local, and got an output as in the pic.Check if its something that you want to get.

[image]

Comment: Hi. I have updated my post, i added console log for child and gchild before the append line. I got the correct elements for grandchilds

Comment: Hi. Yes it is, also I need to see the grandchilds of the childs

Comment: Also, i updated the database table in order for everyone to view it clearly. Kindly check

Comment: I tried changing it to console.log($(child)); as you said. And updated the console log picture in my post

Answer (score 1):

So looking at your console, this line `console.log($("#child"+i).length);` appears to be returning `0` which would mean that the element in question doesn't seem to exist.

Can you log this without the `.length` and make sure that it is still getting the right element.